# How can I add type hints for kwargs that are passed to another class without needing to duplicate my hints and/or docs?

Tags: python, dynamic, type-hinting, python-typing, pydantic

I'm doing some machine learning and I have a `Generator` class that generates text and can do so with several models. I use a Pydantic `Model` to validate its parameters and give me a type-hinted object that's easy to work with throughout the code.

The problem is that I'd like to be able to have an `add_params` method in the `Generator` class that is type hinted just like the pydantic model. But to do this I have to write down the type hints manually in the `add_params` method. This seems like a recipe for disaster since it's not unlikely that I'll change the type hints and docs for the pydantic model and forget to change the `add_params` method or visa versa.

Right now, I'm just using kwargs for `add_params` and referring to the pydantic model when I need to remember what I can pass. But I'm hoping there's a better way to do it.

```py
class GenerationParameters(pydantic.BaseModel):
    # list of all possible parameters and types
    # and some validation methods


class Generator:
    param_list:List[GenerationParameters] = []

    def add_params(model_name:str, **kwargs):
        # load default params for that model
        params_dict = get_default_params_from_model_name(model_name:str)
        # overwrite defaults with passed kwargs
        params_dict.update(kwargs)
        # pass to pydantic model for validation and easy access
        pydantic_params = GenerationParameters(model_name=model_name, **params_dict)
        # add to params list
        self.params_list.append(pydantic_params )
               
    def generate():
        output = []
        for params in param_list:
            output.append(self._generate_from_params(params))
        return output
```

Is there a way to use the type hints for `GenerationParameters` for `add_params` kwargs? Or is there a better way to combine these type hints and docs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't make `Generator.add_params` responsible for constructing an instance of `GenerationParameters`. Let the caller construct it and pass it to the method, which now simply needs to store it for later use.

```
class GenerationParameters(pydantic.BaseModel):
    # list of all possible parameters and types
    # and some validation methods


class Generator:
    param_list:List[GenerationParameters] = []

    def add_params(gp: GenerationParameters):
        self.params_list.append(gp)
          
    def generate(self):
        output = []
        for params in param_list:
            output.append(self._generate_from_params(params))
        return output


g = Generator()
g.add_params(GenerationParameters('model1', foo=3, bar=6))
```

`get_default_params_from_model_name` should be used by a method of `GenerationParameters` to help construct the instance.

Now `Generator` has no responsibility for ensuring `GenerationParameters` is correctly instantiated.

---

Using a `**` parameter is fundamentally at odds with the idea of static type hinting. You are saying "I don't know, statically, what arguments will be provided. I'll just accepted whatever I am given at run time." The fact that you will pass those unknown arguments to a function that *is* statically hinted doesn't matter.

Comment: That makes sense as far as type hinting goes. I'd also like to be able to set defaults params based on the model type however. But maybe that's a question for a different post.

Comment: That's also still a matter for `GenerationParamters` to handle. (I do realize that in some sense, I've just shifted the problem from `Generator` to `GenerationParameter`, but `GenerationParameter` is better situated to handle the type-checking of its own arguments, rather than having to spread it out across both classes.)